# Angular Datepicker are not work proper move on page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

Html code

```
        <div class="col-5 col-md-3 px-0 daterange-picker">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" id="secondDateRange" class="form-control pl-2 pr-1 text-center overflow-"
                name="daterangeInput" daterangepicker [options]="options" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- <input type="text" name="daterangeInput" daterangepicker [options]="options" /> -->
          <!-- <date-range-picker [instanceId]="'secondDateRange'" [options]="options" 
            [controlName]="'secondDateRange'" #dateRangePicker (rangeSelected)="onRangeSelected($event)">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input id="secondDateRange" class="form-control pl-2 pr-1 text-center" type="text" name="dateRange"
                  [value]="displayDateRange" placeholder="Date Range" formControlName="secondDateRange" [disabled]="true" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </date-range-picker> -->
        </div>
```

Please Fix the DatePicker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaMfI.png)

I try to change datepicker but problem are not solved??

Comment: Hello. Stackoverflow is not the maintainer of the date-range-picker. I suggest to contact the maintainer to have answer or to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

use inspect of browser and style your date picker, after that in code use `::ngdeep`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).